# C++ obtener tamaño del buffer de la consola

Tags: c++, consola

### Edit: Gracias al comentario de @Trauma, mire el post que compartio y me inspire para hacer algo parecido con la biblioteca `<conio.h>`

---

### Sources: [Client.cpp](http://pastebin.com/1FKu9A3n) - [Server.cpp](http://pastebin.com/zgTabiqu)

---

Resumen: **¿Es posible obtener el tamaño del buffer de etrada de la consola?** El que contiene lo que vamos escribiendo antes de presionar **Enter** y antes de que `cin` tome los valores para asignarselos a las variables. O el Buffer que contiene la informacion mientras insertamos texto por un `getchar()` o un `scanf()`.

Pregunte en el StackOverflow Oficial, pero me llenaron de votos negativos y no tuve respuesta alguna. Creo que podria resolverlo usando `getch()`, un `switch(){}`, y un `GotoXY()` para la consola, pero ese seria mi ultimo recurso.

---

Estoy usando WinSock2.h para escribir un simple "Command Line Chat" en C++. My IDE es Code::Blocks. Funciona bien, hay un **server.cpp => server.exe** que recive los paquetes enviados por cualquier cliente **client.cpp => client.exe** y luego re-envia el mensaje recivido a todos los clientes disponibles (a excepcion del remitente). Estoy usando **threads** para poder enviar paquetes al mismo tiempo que estoy reciviendo otros.

El **"problema"** es que si estas escribiendo un mensaje y al mismo tiempo otro cliente te manda un paquete, el server remite ese paquete hacia ti, y el thread encargado de gestionar los packetes entrantes lo decifra y lo imprime en la consola de inmediato, cortando el mensaje que estas escribiendo por la mitad (sin mencionar el **'\n'** final que viene por defecto).

---

Ejemplo:
Cliente 1

> Conectandose al Servidor...
>   Conectado bajo la ID: 1
>
> >*aqui empiezo a escri...*

De repente se conecta un segundo Cliente

> Conectandose al Servidor...
>   Conectado bajo la ID: 2
>
> >*Hooolaa que tall! *enter**
>   >

Vuelta al Cliente 1

> Conectandose al Servidor...
>   Conectado bajo la ID: 1
>
> >*aqui empiezo a escri**Cliente 2: Hooolaa que tall!***
>   >*bir mi mensaje *enter**

Finalmente, vuelta al Cliente 2

> Conectandose al Servidor...
>   Conectado bajo la ID: 2
>
> >*Hooolaa que tall! *enter**
>   **Cliente 1: aqui empiezo a escribir mi mensaje**
>   >

---

Mi idea es hacer que el cliente vaya metiendo los mensajes entrantes en una cola, en vez de imprimirlos de inmediato, y que los empieze a des-encolar e imprimir solo cuando el buffer de la consola este vacio (ya sea porque aprete enter, o porque borre todo lo que tenia escrito). (Mi intencion es agregar otro thread que chequee cada 0,02 la longitud de dicho buffer dinamico, y actualize una variable global llamada `bufflen`

```
int bufflen = 0;

void length_test(){
    while (true){
        bufflen = ????????; /*No se que poner, se me ocurre algo como length(consolebuffer); pero ni idea*/
        Sleep(20);
    }
}

int main()
{
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)length_test, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    .
    .
    .

    return 0;
}
```

---

Ya llevo un buen rato averiguando y una de dos, o no hay nada asi de especifico, o no conozco algun concepto clave relevante al tema, para googlearlo (como por ejemplo: "el nombre del buffer que buscas es 'talnombre' "). De todos modos, lo  mas cerca que estuve de encontrar una respuesta fue con [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895987/get-size-of-input-in-console) post de la pagina en ingles, donde alguien hace una pregunta parecida, pero con un objetivo mucho mas simple, entonces las respuestas refieren a como lograr ese objetivo de manera mas sencilla, sin mencionar nada acerca de la longitud del buffer de la consola.

Comment: estoy trabajando en la version del getch(), si para cuando termine no hay respuesta, les comparto lo que hize

Comment: Se ve interesante lo que planteas, si consigo algo te comento, Saludos!

Comment: _Pregunte en el StackOverflow Oficial_ (?) y este es pirata?jeje supongo que te refieres al StackOverflow en ingles

Comment: claro jajajaja, es que ya habia usado en ingles, y no me queria repetir =P

Comment: ¿Por búfer de consola te refieres a `std::cin`? De ser así puedes usar [`peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek).

Comment: ¿buffer de entrada o buffer de salida? el buffer de entrada es el que recibe los datos de, principalmente, el teclado, mientras que el buffer de salida es el que escribe en, normalmente, la consola. Entiendo que te refieres al de salida, no?

Comment: Me temo que no es posible hacerlo en C++ *puro*. Échale un ojo a [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/421871), [How to avoid press enter with any getchar()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1799024). Una respuesta que tal vez te sirva: [Read only one char from cin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42775495)

Comment: Es exactamente lo que @Trauma sugirio!!! capturar la cantidad de caracteres antes de que sean mandados al stdin (Estoy hablando del input) -> necesito un int que se vaya actualizando conforme vayamos escribiendo/borrando caracteres

Comment: Puedes contestar tu mismo a la pregunta abajo puedes ver: Tu respuesta,  pienso que es mejor que dejes la respuesta ahi, en lugar de en la pregunta ademas puedes explicar como lo implementastes asi la pregunta se queda con una respuesta y pueda ayudar mejor a otros, ademas de que al estar el codigo fuera de SO puede que algun dia desaparezca de pastebin. Saludos

Comment: si, es cierto, pero todavia no termino de desarrollarla, el edit del principio es provisional, cuando termine mi proyecto, hare lo que tu dices, saludos

Comment: ya publique mi alternativa, que les parece?

Answer (score 1):

numeric_limits<> es una clase plantilla que te sirve para encontrar distintos valores como min() y max() de tipos básicos como int, float, bool etc. De esta forma tu puedes encontrar el tamaño utilizando el tipo std::streamsize que viene siendo un typedef de otro tipo básico y es utilizado para representar el tamaño del buffer de I/O. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long buffSize = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();

    std::cout << "Tamaño del buffer de entrada: " << buffSize << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Para completar la respuesta estaría bien comentar cómo funciona, no sólo incluir el código sin más.