# ¿Por que no puedo introducir como entrada por consola una cadena de más de 4094 caracteres? (en un programa hecho en C++)

Tags: c++, terminal, codeblocks, ejecutar, windows11

Todo este texto es el que quiero introducir como entrada en la ejecucion de un codigo donde solicito como entrada un string
[image]

En esta imagen muestro la ejecucion del codigo y aqui es donde quiero pegar todo el texto de la imagen anterior pero al pegar aquí todo el texto veo que solo me permite pegar 4094 caracteres cuando la entrada que quiero pegar en verdad tiene mas caracteres
[image]

Aqui imprimo la cantidad de caracteres que tiene la segunda entrada que solicité y pues aqui me doy cuenta que como maximo aceptar 4094 caracteres
[image]

Comment: Nadie introduciria tantos casos de una sola vez por el terminal. Lo habitual es leer los datos de un archivo si son muchos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -2):

Debes considerar que el límite en los datos que pueden leerse por entrada estandar, depende del tamaño del bufer.

En sistemas Unix/Linux, el tamaño predeterminado del búfer de entrada estándar es de 4096 bytes, lo que limita la cantidad de datos que se pueden leer en una sola entrada.

Una solución puede ser aumentar aumentar el tamaño del búfer de entrada estándar en tu programa C++ utilizando la función setbuf o setvbuf. Por ejemplo, puedes aumentar el tamaño del búfer de entrada estándar a 8192 bytes usando la función setbuf de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char input[8192];
    setbuf(stdin, input);
    printf("Ingrese una cadena de hasta 8191 caracteres: ");
    fgets(input, 8192, stdin);
    printf("Cadena ingresada: %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

También puedes considerar cargar la información que necesitas desde un archivo externo.

Te dejo una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55692/c-obtener-tama%C3%B1o-del-buffer-de-la-consola) relacionada con una explicación alternativa.

Comment: copié tu codigo y probé si efectivamente con tu manera se podía ingresar mayor cantidad de caracteres pero para mi sorpresa, el maximo numero de caracteres de ingreso no aumentó, sino que incluso se redujo considerablemente.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.